# I am new in google test and started to work to mock object, after mocking object my original method always getting called

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest, googlemock

**Original prototype of function**

```
virtual void GetSegment(const std::string& polygonId,
                        mi::Uint32& numSegment,
                        std::vector<std::vector<mi::math::Vector_struct<mi::Float32, 3>>>* points,
                        std::vector<mi::Uint32>* exclusive);
```

**Mocking my function**

```
MOCK_METHOD4(GetSegment,
             void(const std::string&, mi::Uint32&, std::vector<std::vector<mi::math::Vector_struct<mi::Float32, 3>>>*,
                  std::vector<mi::Uint32>*));
```

**And here is my action.**

```
mi::Uint32 numSegment = 1;
std::vector<mi::Uint32> exclusive(0);
std::vector<std::vector<mi::math::Vector_struct<mi::Float32, 3> >> points{
    {{50.8981,  213.265, 125},
     {117.287,  184.577, 125},
     {215.488,  129.682, 125},
     {276.487,  92.0992, 125}}};

ON_CALL(*mock.get(), GetSegment(refrenceId, _, _, _)).
  WillByDefault(DoAll(SetArgReferee<1>(numSegment), SetArgPointee<2>(points), SetArgPointee<3>(exclusive)));
```

After calling the function, always my original is getting called.

Comment: How do you call the function (on which instance) ?

Comment: I am calling From my base class instance.

Comment: You should call your mock...

Comment: I am getting the same problem, Whether SetArgPointee can point a vector type?

Comment: Can you please post the function that is actually using the mock? So far you only have defined the mock, and specified what the mock should do when called, but you haven`t shown us the code that is acutally using the it.